# Campo date no Firefox e IE

Tags: php, sql-server

Eu tenho o seguinte código:

```
$dataAssContrato = new DateTime($_POST['dataContrato']);
```

Essa linha funciona perfeitamente no Chrome, mas não no firefox nem no IE, pois quando tento cadastrar uma cada, recebo o seguinte aviso:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message
>   'DateTime::__construct() [datetime.--construct]: Failed to parse
>   time string (25/09/2014) at position 0 (2): Unexpected character'
>
> Exception: DateTime::__construct() [datetime.--construct]: Failed to parse
>   time string (25/09/2014) at position 0 (2): Unexpected character in

Comment: O campo é gravado no formato `d/m/Y`?

Comment: Não sei, não estou conseguindo ver. Coloco echo para ver o formato e aparece outro aviso.

Comment: Mas da última vez que consegui ver entrava no formato Y-m-d.

Comment: Coloque a definição do form, do campo data e a versão do IE/Firefox que ocorre o problema.

Answer (score 4):

Caso a data venha do form no formato `d/m/Y` converta ela para o formato do banco que normalmente é `Y-m-d`.

```
$dataAssContrato = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', trim($_POST['dataContrato']));
$dataFormatada = $dataAssContrato->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: Coloquei o que vc sugeriu e o seguinte aviso apareceu:

Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object

Comment: Mostrou o número 10

Comment: Continua o mesmo erro?

Comment: Sim.
 Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object

Answer (score 1):

A solução proposta pelo perdeu me parece a ideal, mas se estiver com dificuldade em trabalhar o objeto, pode tentar uma solução menos ortodoxa, da seguinte forma:

```
list($d,$m,$y) = explode('/', $_POST['dataContrato']);
$dataAssContrato = new DateTime("$m/$d/$y");
```

Comment: Tentei sua sugestão Eduardo, olha o que apareceu:

Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in
Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in
 

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DateTime::__construct() [<a href='datetime.--construct'>datetime.--construct</a>]: Failed to parse time string (/2014-10-27/) at position 0 (/): Unexpected character' in

 Exception: DateTime::__construct() [<a href='datetime.--construct'>datetime.--construct</a>]: Failed to parse time string (/2014-10-27/) at position 0 (/): Unexpected character in

Comment: Insere essa linha no início do seu código, talvez seu timezone não esteja setado:
date_default_timezone_set("America/Sao_Paulo")

Comment: Continua aparecendo o mesmo aviso de erro.

Comment: É um inferno esse IE!!! Nada ele ta aceitando!! MORRE IE!! Hehehehehe

Comment: Cara, veja a versão do seu php se é não é < 5.3.
Tenta isso:

$dataAssContrato = new DateTime(date("c", mktime(0,0,0,$m,$d,$y)));

Comment: Consegui ajustar isso mudando o tipo de dado no BD, troquei de datetime pra smalldatetime.
Outra coisa, realmente, pode ser problema de versão do meu php, não estou conseguindo atualizá-lo para a última versão, pois estou usando o programa Vertrigo para rodar no meu windows, pq o wammp eu não consegui instalar aqui.

Mesmo assim, muito obrigado pela atenção de vocês.

Answer (score 1):

Conforme o @perdeu já mencionou, é mais facil você utilizar o método DateTime::[createFromFormat](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php).
Sugiro ainda testar a data para garantir que não tenha erros, de modo que o código ficaria parecido com a sugestão do @perdeu:

```
$dataAssContrato = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', trim($_POST['dataContrato']));
if (!($dataAssContrato instanceof DateTime)) {
  die('Data Inválida!!'); /* Ou qualquer tratamento que achar necessário */
}
$dataFormatada = $dataAssContrato->format('Y-m-d');
```

---

Ressalto ainda que o navegador nada tem a ver com o código executado no lado servidor (php neste caso). Oque provavelmente está ocasionando o problema é a formatação dos campos date.
É bem provavel que você esteja utilizando um formato americano **Y-m-d** no Chrome/Chromium e um formato brasileiro **d/m/Y** no Firefox e IE.

Comment: Mas eu consigo formatar, tanto para Y-m-d quanto d/m/Y

Comment: Certo @GustavoSevero, mas nos mostre um trecho do código HTML que gera estes formulários para poder lhe ajudar melhor.